# Generating UUID`s with Xalan instead of Saxon in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to use Xalan instead of Saxon in XSLT to produce random UUID`s

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"  
xmlns:uuid="xalan://java.util.UUID">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="uid" select="uuid:randomUUID()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$uid"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The reason that i am using Xalan instead of Saxon is;it is free.
So i need to buy Saxon to use it for my purpose.

The idea is when i try to transform an XML file,i want to produce this UUID`s and put it the node that i want.

The reference that i am using:

http://www.pure-xml.com/cblog/index.php?/archives/8-Generating-UUIDs-with-XSL-and-Java.html

The error of the execution is :

```
 XSL transformation failed
XTDE1420: Error in XPath 2.0 expression
Unknown function - Name and number of arguments do not match any function 
signature in the static context - 'xalan://java.util.UUID:randomUUID'
```

Comment: Xalan does not support XSLT 2.0 at all so I am not sure why your post mentions using Xalan together with XSLT 2.0. And the error message looks as if it comes from Saxon so somehow if your intention is to use Xalan then you have not done that I think.

Comment: What might be the solution instead of Xalan and Saxon in XSLT 2.0 then ?

Comment: Well, to use that Java class to create a UUID you don't need a specific version of XSLT I think, you need to write a Java program to call that class and then to pass in the generated value as a parameter to your XSLT stylesheet, whether you do that with an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor does not seem to matter. If you really want to do the Java code directly from your XSLT then you will have to explore the support your XSLT processor has for that, with Saxon 9 HE see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ for that but it requires writing Java code too.

Comment: Yes i have tried it with Saxon HE but it is not working,Java says that you need a Saxon PE or above to use it in XSLT (which is not free).I am looking for a free solutions first of all.

Comment: Using a parameter or integrated extension functions is "free", you only need to write the code in Java.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a UUID in **Java** using **Xalan**:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
exclude-result-prefixes="java">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <uuid>
        <xsl:value-of select="java:java.util.UUID.randomUUID()"/>
    </uuid>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKi

---

Note that not all Xalan versions support using Java as an extension.

Comment: Thanks but i have an errror Error in XPath expression
Unknown function - Name and number of arguments do not match any function signature in the static context - 'http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java:java.util.UUID.randomUUID' and i need to use XSLT 2.0 not 1.0

Comment: @Sojimanatsu You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKi (when the service is not down, which it often is). Check which version of Xalan you're trying this with.

Comment: Thanks but i still need it in xslt 2.0 which is not supporting so I guess Xalan is not an option for me now.Since Saxon is also not working i dont know what to do about this

Comment: You did not say **why** you need XSLT 2.0. I suppose you could rewrite your stylesheet in XSLT 1.0 - but that would be a different question.

Comment: Because the code is  already written in XSLT 2.0 and i cant change it now

Comment: You **are** changing it by adding the UUID, are you not? Seems like you want to have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: Like so many users, the OP wants a free lunch. He wants XSLT 2.0, but he wants someone else to pay for it. One option might be to use Saxon-B 9.1, which was the last open-source release with support for direct calls to Java extension functions.

Comment: @MichaelKay Lunch, cake - same difference.